# Change the displayed shipping total in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

I need to change shipping price programmatically:

```
<?php
   $percentage = 50;
   $current_shipping_cost = WC()->cart->get_cart_shipping_total();
   echo $current_shipping_cost * $percentage / 100;
?>
```

Unfortunately it's not working and I always get 0 *(zero)*.

How to change the displayed shipping total with a total based on a calculated discount percentage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will displayed shipping total based on a percentage. There is 2 ways:

**1) First way** with a custom function.

In the function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme):

```
function wc_display_cart_shipping_total( $percentage = 100 )
{
    $cart  = WC()->cart;
    $total = __( 'Free!', 'woocommerce' );

    if ( 0 < $cart->get_shipping_total() ) {
        if ( $cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) {
            $total = wc_price( ( $cart->shipping_total + $cart->shipping_tax_total ) * $percentage / 100 );
            if ( $cart->shipping_tax_total > 0 && ! wc_prices_include_tax() ) {
                $total .= ' <small class="tax_label">' . WC()->countries->inc_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
            }
        } else {
            $total = wc_price( $cart->shipping_total * $percentage / 100  );
            if ( $cart->shipping_tax_total > 0 && wc_prices_include_tax() ) {
                $total .= ' <small class="tax_label">' . WC()->countries->ex_tax_or_vat()  . '</small>';
            }
        }
    }
    return  $totals;
}
```

Usage:

```
<?php echo wc_display_cart_shipping_total(50); ?>
```

---

**2) Second way** with a filter hook.

In the function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_total', 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_total_filter_callback', 11, 2 );
function woocommerce_cart_shipping_total_filter_callback( $total, $cart )
{
    // HERE set the percentage
    $percentage = 50;

    if ( 0 < $cart->get_shipping_total() ) {
        if ( $cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) {
            $total = wc_price( ( $cart->shipping_total + $cart->shipping_tax_total ) * $percentage / 100 );
            if ( $cart->shipping_tax_total > 0 && ! wc_prices_include_tax() ) {
                $total .= ' <small class="tax_label">' . WC()->countries->inc_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
            }
        } else {
            $total = wc_price( $cart->shipping_total * $percentage / 100  );
            if ( $cart->shipping_tax_total > 0 && wc_prices_include_tax() ) {
                $total .= ' <small class="tax_label">' . WC()->countries->ex_tax_or_vat()  . '</small>';
            }
        }
    }
    return  $totals;
}
```

Usage:

```
<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_shipping_total(); ?>
```